# Exim redirect to smart host based on mx record

Tags: exim

I'm looking at have exim redirect a subset of mail to one of our smarthosts based on the looked up mx record. Currently I can do this by specifying all of the domains and using a manualroute router, but I'd like it to be automatic going forward.

Example:

DNS => Domain1.com in mx 10 subhost.outdomain.com

Exim would then need to have a condition in the manualrouter based on that mxdomain.

Anyone know how to do this without an external script? Exim already knows the mx_domain while processing so it should be about to do it.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I'm aware, exim only becomes aware of the MX record in a destination domain when it attempts SMTP delivery via the SMTP transport. What you need to route the mail to a different transport depending on the value of the MX record.

I don't believe there's any way to get a *router* to know the MX record of the destination domain without using an external script. I'm prepared for someone to come along and tell me I'm wrong though...

Answer (score 0):

The route_data variable is expanded, so you can use

`route_data = ${lookup dnsdb{>: mxh=Domain1.com}{$value}fail}`

It doesn't respect MX priotities, as I haven't found out how to sort in string expansions.